# jquery .show() and .hide() not working in safari - adding spinner to <a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, safari

I have some very basic code that acts as a loading gif for a webpage:

The loading and content containers sit in my base template. The

---

```
//header

<a href="{{ url_for('welcome', id=id, profile=profile) }}" onclick="spinner();" class="home">Home</a>

//more html

<div id="loading">
    <img src="/static/images/Loading.gif" class="ajax-loader">
</div>

<div id="content">

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function spinner() {
        console.log('fire');
        $("#loading").show();
        $("#content").hide();
    }
</script>
```

---

```
div#loading {
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    background: white;
}

.ajax-loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

My code works perfectly well in firefox and chrome, but not in safari or on ios.

ps. I have checked that my function is working, the console shows 'fire' which i print straight after the onclick().

**Edit**

This is the only error in the console:

`[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) (jquery-ui.min.css, line 0)`

**Update 1**

I have added a class to my `<a href="url" class="..."` and updated my javascript to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( ".spin_click" ).click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('hiding content');
            $(".content").hide();
            console.log('show spinner');
            $(".se-pre-con").show();
            console.log('waiting now...');
        });
    });
</script>

#html

<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
    <div class="content">

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

I can get safari to show the `se-pre-con`div when I click on a link, however it completely disables the href link. Is it possible to pursue the link click having executed the .show() command in the jquery? Perhaps I have misunderstood `preventDefault();` - but I thought it might be able to act as a workaround. **The issue still only exists in safari**

**Update 2**

As suggested by @maximast, I have decided to use addClass and removeClass. As usual it works in chrome and firefox, but not safari. The code is the same, I have just added a `hide` class which is added and removed as necessary.

If I use the safari inspector and remove the hide class manually, **the spinner does show up**. When I click on a link in the page to trigger the jquery function, I can see the `hide` class removed correctly from the `div`. However, even though the `hide` class is removed, the spinner does not appear. Perhaps I am missing something obvious here.

Here are the libraries i am using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

**Update 3**

Here is a link to a test page. There is a link which puts the app to sleep for 3 seconds giving enough time for the spinner to trigger. The spinner sits in the logo. The test page will show the spinner working in a Chrome and Firefox, but not safari. The implementation with this button is exactly the same as used elsewhere in my app.

http://ec2-54-88-245-245.compute-1.amazonaws.com/spinner-test

I have changed the link in the logo to: `<a href='#'` which for the first time render the spinner in all three browsers. (progress!). However when you click on the 'Click to trigger spinner.' link, the following happens:

1. Chrome - spinner works first time.
2. Firefox - spinner works first time, however there were a couple of occasions when I had to click it a second time.
3. Safari - no luck.

Here is the flask code with the managing the spinner-test page:

```
@app.route('/spinner-test', methods=['GET'])
def spinner():
    return render_template('spinner-test.html')


@app.route('/wait', methods=['GET'])
def wait():
    time.sleep(3)
    return redirect(url_for('spinner'))
```

Comment: And you're sure the anchor doesn't redirect

Comment: Do you get anything in the console apart from the `fire` log?

Comment: This isn't your issue, but get rid of the `javascript:` label. It does nothing useful.

Comment: Since you seem to have an element ID somewhere called `loading`, try changing the name of the function to some other name.

Comment: `jquery-ui.min.css - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)` this is the only error. Change the function name did not help. Removed `javascript:`

Comment: any errors in Safari's console?

Comment: The onclick event is triggered when a new page is loaded, but the page takes a while to load, hence the spinner.

Comment: did you try to use jquery to add a click listener that trigger your function?
Something like $(".home").on("click", function(){ /*your code*/})

Comment: Can you add some of the HTML to make it a [mcve]? So far, code posted is not enough to replicate the issue for me

Comment: i had assumed that the trigger wasn't the issue seeing as i was able to log to my console.

Comment: *"The onclick event is triggered when a new page is loaded..."* That seems wrong, unless you're calling the function somewhere. Have you tested the `.length` of the two jQuery objects you're creating?

Comment: sorry, that wasn't clear on my side. i mean that when a link is clicked, ie. some data is generated in the backend and a new page shown, while this request is processed in the backend, the front end shows `<div id="loading">`

Comment: Are you putting your jquery and javascript code inside a `ready` handler? - i.e. inside a `$(function(){...});` block? - it seems like you are mixing plain JS with Jquery event listeners so they may not be playing along very well

Comment: here is a plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/glXfAj1gWac6nNs8B7H4?p=preview

i tested it on safari (v9.1.2).

Comment: Yeah, at this point I doubt it's an issue with the snippet of code you provided (as all of the examples are working fine on my Safari). It's more likely an issue with your Safari (try updating it), or as @ochi mentioned, perhaps some dependencies are missing. I would perhaps check if there's any events bound to `.spin_click`.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to either provide a more complete [mcve] or point us to a test page where the issue is happening (i.e. a URL to a test page) - also, just removing the `hide` class from the spinner may not be enough (there could be some parent classes also being hidden.  We cannot tell the hierarchy of the DOM so we can't tell exactly where the issue lies)

Comment: updated the question to show a test page. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update - I updated my answer as it was too long to put in a comment.

Comment: Hi @user3939059, try my answer ;) Updated it a while ago...

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you function is named `spinner`, yet you're attempting to fire `loading()` inside your `a` tag (`onclick="javascript:loading();`). Changing your function name to `loading` should fix it.

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nvzge1e8/5/

**Edit for updated question:**

You need to prevent the event, if you stick `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your function, it should play the animation. Do note, doing this will prevent your link from actually sending your user to the page, so you may need to add a timed redirect to whatever page you're sending them to.

Example code:

```
 $(function() {
 $(".spin_click").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault()
     $("#logo_spinner").attr("src", "/static/images/loaders/spinner.gif");
     $('.content').addClass('hide');
     setTimeout(function() {
         window.location.href = "/wait";
     }, 4000);

 });
});
```

Comment: sorry that was a mistake on my part, i just the function name as per a comment earlier on. The functions names are the same in my code. The discrepancy is only on SO

Comment: Ah, no worries. Are you sure you've added jQuery before this function? Does my jsfiddle link work for you?

Comment: i load jquery in the head: `script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` but it works in firefox, so surely the position of jquery wouldn't make a difference. unfortunately, the jsfiddle doesnt work for me

Comment: Can you add `console.log (typeof jQuery)` to the top of your function, and let me know what the console logs?

Comment: the log says: `function`

Comment: Alright, that indicates jQuery is loading fine. What version of Safari are you working with?

Comment: `Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7)`

Comment: it works in firefox, but again does not work in safari logs: `n [div id="loading"] Could not fetch properties. Object may no longer exist.`

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to reproduce the issue with the code provided. However, I am adding an answer with a simple version of what you want to accomplish.

My guess is that the code not provided is more complex than you describe (or some dependencies are missing).

Since you already are using jQuery, I am giving you my answer using that library as well.

(***updated***: added other libraries, used by the OP, to test if their presence introduces the issue described)

See sample code below:

```js
$(function() {
  // add event listener to home (class) - 
  // used instead of inline binding using 'onclick'
  $('.home').on('click', function() {
    console.log('show spinner');
    // show spinner right away
    $("#loading").show();

    console.log('waiting now...');

    // simulate delay in fetching backend response (delay is 3 secs)
    // contains the callback function to be invoked after your response is completed
    setTimeout(function() {
      // hide spinner
      console.log('hide spinner');
      $("#loading").hide();

      // show content
      console.log('show content');
      $("#content").show();
    }, 3 * 1000); // time is in ms so 1000ms = 1 sec (3*1000=3secs)

  });
});
```

```css
div#loading {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  background: white;
}
.ajax-loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>


<header>
  Header here
</header>
<hr/>

<a href="#" class="home">Home</a>

<div id="loading">
  <img class="ajax-loader" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/akN6H.png?s=48&amp;g=1" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="avatar-me js-avatar-me">
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="content">

  content will be loaded here

</div>

<footer>footer here
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. i have added the changes you suggest and unfortunately see the same behaviour. It works with firefox, but not safari

Comment: @user3939059 any error in console? - I will try safari shortly

Comment: there is no error. as an fyi, your code also works in chrome. but still no luck with safari or iOS

Comment: @user3939059 I am sorry I didn't get back to you... I did try it on safari (on Sierra) and it did work for me as expected. - is it possible that you have other JS libraries that might be interfering with this?

Comment: I tried Safari Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7) - which version are you trying it with?

Comment: @user3939059 oh, and which version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: Hi, jsut adde the scripts being loaded into the question. the version is `2.1.1`

Comment: @user3939059 I added the dependencies and tested it in Safari again, I still cannot reproduce the issue.  I am afraid there is something else in your code causing this issue.  Can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this in Safari but you could try

```
$("#loading").fadeIn(0);
$("#content").fadeOut(0);
```

But make sure to remove the

```
display: none
```

from your CSS

Comment: this makes the `loading` div appear the whole time

Comment: the issue seems to be safari-specific (OP says it works on FF and chrome) so unless you can replicate the issue (which you didn't as you didn't test it in Safari) - this is not a good answer.  I recommend testing it in safari or remove it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry haven't tried reproducing your bug but unless you must use `elem.hide()` and `elem.show()`.

Alternatively, You can work with addClass and removeClass functions

```
$('#loading').addClass('hide');
$('#loading').removeClass('hide');
```

with `.hide { display: none; }`

works perfectly on safari too.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have tried with `addClass` and `removeClass` and can see that the js works, the `hide` class is added and removed respectively. However the spinner still does not appear in safari. Which makes me think this could be a `css` issue.

Comment: why would you assume there is a bug in `hide()` and `show()` functions (pretty basic functionality) with such a popular library such as jQuery?  Don't you think that it would have been fixed by now? did you look at their issue tracker to see if there is such a thing (maybe with certain versions of Safari only)? - no, instead, you assume there is a bug (blame someone else) and provide an alternative that, basically, does the exact same thing as the functions :( - (if you look at their code, it does what you suggest)

Comment: not blaming anyone just trying to help the guy get past his problem.

Comment: edited, now am not assuming anything hope that works for you. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$('elem').show()` and `$('elem').hide()` try using...

```
$('elem').attr( 'data-display', 'block');
$('elem').attr( 'data-display', 'none');
```

In CSS add...

Attribute selector used twice to increase specificity ;)

```
[data-display][data-display='none'] {
  display:none!important;
}
[data-display][data-display='block'] {
  display:block!important;
}
```

Code will look like this...

```js
$('h1').attr( 'data-display', 'block');
$('h2').attr( 'data-display', 'none');
```

```css
[data-display][data-display='none'] {
  display:none!important;
}
[data-display][data-display='block'] {
  display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>I'm displayed</h1>
<h2>I'm hidden</h2>
<p>
  I'm unaffected ;)
</p>
```

This will hide it (even if there is some css forcing visibility by using `!important`), if not try increasing specificity of selector even more. Inspecting the element would help ;)

Comment: Since what version does jQuery support setting inline `important`? As I remember, it didn't.

Comment: Hi @Qwertiy, Yeah, thanks for pointing out updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue as the OP, I am simply trying to have an element display only when on IOS, show/hide do not work, any combination of add class/remove class is not working either.

In my case I am working on progressive web application and this issue has eaten half of my day.

I even have an alert in the same function method that tries to fire the show, and/or remove class. This alert fires as expected but the element never appears. If I simply remove the hide class and reload the page it appears, if I change the element to show by default in CSS it works, but nothing I have tried so far gets the element to appear via JS. I have tried it in the CSS spreadsheet and with inline style. I've tried using visibility, display none/block, and simply hiding/unhiding via JS. Nothing works on IOS. Works fine in Chrome, Internet Explorer, Edge, Firefox, and various other browser. It just won't work in Safari on IOS and frankly I am stumped as to why.

If I ever get to the bottom of this issue I will post an answer but I have to say this is proving to be one of the more inexplicable situations that I have encountered in a 20 year development career.

**!!UPDATE!!**

Fixed it yes! After much stress, a colleague suggested it may be a popup blocker in Safari... he suggested tying it to a click in order to prove the concept.

At that precise moment an error modal popped up all on its own which led me to think... wait a minute - how does that work. It doesn't happen on page load! There is a delay!

And **VOILA** - wrapping the show functionality in a very small setTimeout function (10ms) solves the problem.

In my case I am adding functionality to replicate the Android PWA "add to home screen" functionality for IOS, so when the device is detected as IOS and when the PWA is not already on the home screen, the user is gently prompted to add it.

Comment: I am wondering if this might be the cause. OP: are you/were you using Bootstrap by any chance?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005067/if-else-statement-not-working-in-safari-jquery/51005505#51005505