# jQuery hide and show not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I wrote this small jQuery script to hide and show some elements on the page. While it is working perfectly on Chrome in Safari it is not working. The issue is in `$('#uploadButton').on('click' . . .`The click event is caught because the first console is printed but the hide and show not at all.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
    var input = $(this),
        numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
});


    $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

        $('#uploadButton').show();

        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
            log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

        if( input.length ) {
            input.val(log);
        } else {
            if( log ) alert(log);
        }


    });

    /*PROBLEM ONLY IN THIS CLICK HANDLER*/
    /*only the first console.log is working*/

    $('#uploadButton').on('click',function(){
        console.log('test');
        $('#spinner').show();
        $('#uploadButton').hide();

    });


});
```

Comment: so what ur saying is that it logs, but it doesn't doesn't hide the upload button or show the spinner?

Comment: exactly @ahitt6345

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40577762/4309643 this one may be some help. He uses a different way of making things dissappear. and it works in safari for me anyway