# Javascript/JQuery error message didn't hide in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my registration form I have some validation logic which works perfectly fine in Chrome but in Safari error message don't disappear below form after filling empty fields. It looks like `show()` and `hide()` doesn't work and I don't now why because based on this https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html it should worked.

```
if (registrationsForm.length > 0) {
  var emailField = $('#users-registrations-email');
  var emailConfirmationField = $('#users-registrations-email-confirmation');
  var emailInvalidMsg = $('.bank-employees-users-registration__registrations__not-identical-email');
  var obligatoryInvalidMsg = $('.bank-employees-users-registration__registrations__email--invalid');

  submit.on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (emailField.val() !== emailConfirmationField.val() && emailField.length > 0) {
      emailInvalidMsg.show();
      emailField.addClass("invalid");
      emailConfirmationField.addClass("invalid");
      emailConfirmationField[0].setCustomValidity('Incorrect confirmation email');
      if (emailField.val() !== '') obligatoryInvalidMsg.hide();
    } else {
      emailConfirmationField[0].setCustomValidity('');
    }

    validateEmail();

    var invalidInput = $('input:invalid');

    if (invalidInput.length === 0 && !fileInput.hasClass('invalid')) {
      form.submit();
    } else {
      invalidInput.addClass('invalid');
      validateInput();
    }
  });
}
```

Function which is responsible for input validation:

```
function validateInput() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':valid')) {
      $(this).removeClass('invalid');
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit**

This is a code snippet from view

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="floating-label bank-employees-users-registration__registrations-input--wrapper">
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: "bank-employees-users-registration__registrations-input floating-field", id: "users-registrations-email", placeholder: t('.email'), required: true, aria_required: true %>
  <%= f.label :email, t('.email'), class: "floating-label-placeholder" %>
  <span class="bank-employees-users-registration__registrations__not-identical-email">
    <%= t('.email_not_identical') %>
  </span>
  <span
    class="bank-employees-users-registration__registrations-input--invalid-msg bank-employees-users-registration__registrations__email--invalid"
    id="bank-employees-users-registration__registrations__email--invalid">
    <%= t'.obligatory' %></span>
  <% if @registration_form.errors.full_messages_for(:email).first %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <div class="error-explanation">
      <%= t('activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.taken') %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Edit2**

Maybe this will be helpful - as you see there are some email validations where two email address has to be equal. When I provide different email address it shows me error message that they are not equal but if I correct them, the error will be changed to - `this field is required`. I was trying to implement this solution [jquery .show() and .hide() not working in safari - adding spinner to <a href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365553/jquery-show-and-hide-not-working-in-safari-adding-spinner-to-a-href/40577762#40577762) but without any positive results.

Comment: The problem could be related with this statement. => emailField.val() !== ''

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57001647/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML and CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: I also recommend you attach to the submit event instead of a button click

Comment: @AhmetRemziEKMEKCI what do you mean? if it works in Chrome why it doesn't in Safari? I think it's a pretty standard function.

Comment: Please post HTML!!! In a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Why not get rid of all that and use HTML5 fields? They have client-side validations that work across browsers and you can validate input on the server side using model validations, let Rails deal with all that.

I know it may be a bit of upfront investment into refactoring all that but otherwise things will only get worse in the long term if you keep doing what you're doing.

Also look at the [Bootstrap form gem](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap_form) in case you're using Bootstrap.

Comment: I was thinking about that but unfortunately I can't do it. This is just a little code snippet from the whole app which is written this way and I have to be in line with it.

Comment: I think then it will be rewritten to React, but is there any other solution for now?